# .bat file not running SAS jobs

Tags: sas

This is my .bat file. When I run this inside a SAS program it starts 2 parallel processes and completes. But when I double click on the .bat file it flashes a black terminal and closes. Nothing runs. Please advise.

```
%let log= 'C:\Users\XXXXb\';

%let loc1= 'C:\Users\XXXXb\Documents\My SAS Files\9.4\q2012.sas';
%let loc2= 'C:\Users\XXXXb\Documents\My SAS Files\9.4\q2013.sas';


systask command  "sas &loc1  -log &log.log "
         taskname=sas1
         status  =stat_sas1;
systask command  "sas &loc2  -log &log.log "
         taskname=sas2
         status  =stat_sas2;
waitfor _all_ sas1 sas2;
```

Comment: Try the command at the command line. Are you sure that it will find the SAS command?  Perhaps you need to give it the full path of where SAS is on your computer.  Also does the command like the use of single quotes around a file name? Or does it need double quotes? Also note that you are using the -LOG option to tell both programs to write to the same file.

Comment: That file is not a .bat file. It is a SAS program.

Comment: You're right.  I looked up the command to put in a .bat file.

Comment: Start/w C:\SAS\SAS.exe –sysin C:\chen\prog3.sas

Comment: All the quotes are correct. It works in SAS and now I know that the bat file should only contain commands not SAS code.

Answer (score 0):

You have SAS code inside of a `.bat` file.  DOS batch files use their own language/syntax.  My guess is you want to rename your file to `.sas` not `.bat` and then call it via SAS.  Also note that both your tasks will attempt to use the same logfile so whichever one can't open write access to the file will fail.  Make sure they are using different log file names.

Comment: SAS didn't overwrite the log file, it just created 2 log files with the same name as the programs and put them in the location I specified for the log.

Comment: You have a directory named "log"?  I think whether -log wants a filename or a pathname might vary based on what operating system you are running SAS.